# LiipImagineBundle thumbnails doesn't work

Tags: symfony, liipimaginebundle

I am just trying to get working LiipImagineBundle.

Ok, all I got so far:

- Installed using composer

  - $ php composer.phar require "liip/imagine-bundle:dev-master"
- Enabled bundle in AppKernel.php

  - new Liip\ImagineBundle\LiipImagineBundle(),
- Added to routing.yml

  - _imagine path
- Added liip_imagine filter in config.yml

  Checked using php app/console router:debug and path _imagine_my_thumb exist.

But after using:

```
<img src="{{ '/relative/path/to/image.jpg' | imagine_filter('my_thumb') }}" />
```

image is not rendered, path is simply not found error.

prod.log says that Route _imagine_my_thumb does not exist, although it exist, because it's displayed using router:debug for both environments.

Answer (score 0):

You know that you should replace `'/relative/path/to/image.jpg'` with your image path?
Make sure your file exists.

A working example

config:

```
liip_imagine:
    driver:               gd
    web_root:             %kernel.root_dir%/../web
    data_root:            %kernel.root_dir%/../app
    cache_mkdir_mode:     0777
    cache_prefix:         /media/cache
    cache:                web_path
    cache_clearer:        true
    data_loader:          filesystem
    controller_action:    liip_imagine.controller:filterAction
    formats:              []
    filter_sets:
        avatar:
            filters:
                thumbnail: { size: [40, 40], mode: outbound }
        profile:
            filters:
                relative_resize: { widen: 500 }
```

html:

```
<img src="{{ 'uploads/images/filename.jpg' | imagine_filter('avatar') }}" alt="image">
enter code here
```

routing.yml:

```
_imagine:
    resource: .
    type:     imagine
```

**Remark**: My source folder is in the app folder (see: data_root)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and after enable of php_fileinfo extension in php.ini render start to work.